# Select from row 2 to end row in Python Numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, indexing

As you know in `MATLAB` we can select row 10 to end row using `data[2:end,:]`. What is equivalent function for `Python Numpy`?

Comment: you mean like `a[10:]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use slicing of arrays

```
In [36]: arr = np.random.rand(5,2)

In [37]: arr
Out[37]:
array([[ 0.82932675,  0.77821086],
       [ 0.18996528,  0.37819648],
       [ 0.65644962,  0.14059714],
       [ 0.85267293,  0.28586828],
       [ 0.0991293 ,  0.29407596]])

In [38]: arr[2:, ]
Out[38]:
array([[ 0.65644962,  0.14059714],
       [ 0.85267293,  0.28586828],
       [ 0.0991293 ,  0.29407596]])
```